How to remove styling if the height of the screen less than the element height
I have centered the element by the height of the screen using absolute positioning.However, when the height of the screen is less than the element width, it is cutting the part of the element making its top unreachable.
How can I add and remove styling if the height of the screen is less than the height of the element?

.wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    background-color: white;
    gap: 1rem;
    width: 45%;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 4rem;
    
}




//object idea - Coding Artist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEs3IL6UyvE//

let products = {
  data: [{
      productName: "Fantasy",
      heart: "./icons/heart.svg",
      heartCount: 2547,
      category: "Salmon, Shrimp",
      content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu mei posse possim atomorum, vix cu fabellas assueverit. Vel ad option partiendo maiestatis, nec affert appetere te, his.",
      picture: "./images/pexels-diego-pontes-901015-2323391.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Spring",
      heart: "./icons/heart.svg",
      heartCount: 2547,
      category: "Veggie",
      content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu mei posse possim atomorum, vix cu fabellas assueverit. Vel ad option partiendo maiestatis, nec affert appetere te, his.",
      picture: "./images/pexels-pixabay-357756.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Rainbow",
      heart: "./icons/heart.svg",
      heartCount: 2547,
      category: "Salmon, Tuna, Unagi",
      content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu mei posse possim atomorum, vix cu fabellas assueverit. Vel ad option partiendo maiestatis, nec affert appetere te, his.",
      picture: "./images/pexels-freestockpro-3147493.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Unique",
      heart: "./icons/heart.svg",
      heartCount: 2547,
      category: "Salmon, Tuna, Unagi, Shrimp",
      content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu mei posse possim atomorum, vix cu fabellas assueverit. Vel ad option partiendo maiestatis, nec affert appetere te, his.",
      picture: "./images/pexels-photo-248444.webp",
    },
    {
      productName: "Perfection",
      heart: "./icons/heart.svg",
      heartCount: 2547,
      category: "Salmon",
      content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu mei posse possim atomorum, vix cu fabellas assueverit. Vel ad option partiendo maiestatis, nec affert appetere te, his.",
      picture: "./images/pexels-isabella-mendes-107313-858501.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Style",
      heart: "./icons/heart.svg",
      heartCount: 2547,
      category: "Salmon, Tuna, Unagi, Shrimp",
      content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu mei posse possim atomorum, vix cu fabellas assueverit. Vel ad option partiendo maiestatis, nec affert appetere te, his.",
      picture: "./images/pexels-rajesh-tp-749235-2098143.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Dreamy",
      heart: "./icons/heart.svg",
      heartCount: 2547,
      category: "Salmon",
      content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu mei posse possim atomorum, vix cu fabellas assueverit. Vel ad option partiendo maiestatis, nec affert appetere te, his.",
      picture: "./images/pexels-viniciusbenedit-3620705.jpg",
    },
    {
      productName: "Spicy",
      heart: "./icons/heart.svg",
      heartCount: 2547,
      category: "Shrimp",
      content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu mei posse possim atomorum, vix cu fabellas assueverit. Vel ad option partiendo maiestatis, nec affert appetere te, his.",
      picture: "./images/pexels-catscoming-699544.jpg",
    },
  ],
};

for (let i of products.data) {
  let card = document.createElement("div");
  card.classList.add("card", "i.category");

  //image

  let imgContainer = document.createElement("div");
  imgContainer.classList.add("image-container");
  let image = document.createElement("img");
  image.classList.add("product-img");
  image.setAttribute("src", i.picture);
  imgContainer.appendChild(image);
  card.appendChild(imgContainer);
  document.getElementById("products").appendChild(card);
  card.setAttribute("title", i.category);

  image.addEventListener("error", () => {
    image.style.display = "none"; // Hide the broken image
    image.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "#d9d9d9"; // Set background color
  });

  //content

  let content = document.createElement("div");
  content.classList.add("content");
  card.appendChild(content);

  //content title and likes section

  let contentHead = document.createElement("div");
  contentHead.classList.add("contentHead");
  let productTitle = document.createElement("h2");
  productTitle.classList.add("productTitle");
  productTitle.innerText = i.productName;

  let likesSection = document.createElement("div");
  likesSection.classList.add("likesSection");
  let likesIcon = document.createElement("img");
  likesIcon.setAttribute("src", "./icons/heart.svg");
  likesIcon.classList.add("likesIcon");
  let likesCount = document.createElement("p");
  likesCount.classList.add("likeCount");
  likesCount.innerText = i.heartCount;

  content.appendChild(contentHead);
  contentHead.appendChild(productTitle);
  contentHead.appendChild(likesSection);
  likesSection.appendChild(likesIcon);
  likesSection.appendChild(likesCount);

  likesIcon.addEventListener("error", () => {
    likesIcon.setAttribute(
      "src",
      "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Heart_coraz%C3%B3n.svg"
    );
  });

  //gray line devider
  let line = document.createElement("hr");
  line.classList.add("product-line");
  content.appendChild(line);

  //item category

  let itemCategory = document.createElement("p");
  itemCategory.classList.add("item-category");
  itemCategory.innerText = i.category;
  content.appendChild(itemCategory);

  //description

  let itemDescription = document.createElement("p");
  itemDescription.classList.add("itemDescription");
  itemDescription.innerText = i.content;
  content.appendChild(itemDescription);

  //read more
  let readMore = document.createElement("p");
  readMore.classList.add("readMore");
  readMore.innerText = "Read more >>>";
  content.appendChild(readMore);
}

let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".category-button");
let cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
let buttonArr = [];

buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let buttonValue = button.innerText;
    button.classList.toggle("active-button");
    if (button.classList.contains("active-button")) {
      buttonArr.push(buttonValue);
    }
    if (button.classList.contains("active-button") == false) {
      let unwantedButtonValue = buttonValue;
      let index = buttonArr.indexOf(unwantedButtonValue);
      buttonArr.splice(index, 1);
    }
    buttonArr.sort();
    console.log(buttonsString);
  });

  buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      cards.forEach((card) => {
        let cardCategories;
        cardCategories = card
          .getAttribute("title")
          .split(",")
          .map(function(value) {
            return value.trim();
          })
          .sort();
        console.log(cardCategories);
        //toggle & some idea - Yogi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79091911/item-categories-filtering-with-multiple-categories-javascript
        card.classList.toggle(
          "inactive-card", !buttonArr.some((name) => cardCategories.includes(name)) // boolean
        );

        //Google idea

        let allInactive = Array.from(buttons).every(
          (button) => !button.classList.contains("active-button")
        );
        if (allInactive) {
          card.classList.remove("inactive-card");
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  background-color: white;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 40%;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 13px 27px -5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 8px 16px -8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 4rem;
}

.logo-phrase {
  color: #FF3D00;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo-phrase-red {
  color: white;
  background-color: #FF3D00;
}

.hr-h1 {
  width: 10%;
  align-self: center;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.nav-buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.category-button {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border-radius: 0.8rem;
  border: 1.5px solid #FF3D00;
  color: #FF3D00;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.active-button {
  background-color: #FF3D00;
  color: white;
}

#products {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.active-card {
  display: flex;
}

.inactive-card {
  display: none;
}

.image-container {
  width: 35%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.product-img {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  height: 10.5rem;
  object-fit: cover;
  padding: 1px;
}

.content {
  width: 65%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.contentHead {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.likesSection {
  display: flex;
  width: 15%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.likesIcon {
  width: 20%;
  align-self: center;
}

.likeCount {
  color: #FF3D00;
  align-self: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.product-line {
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.item-category {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.readMore {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FF3D00;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 3500px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 65%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 2500px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 75%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 2100px) {
  .wrap {
    position: static;
    top: 15%;
    transform: none;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    width: 85%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1700px) {
  .wrap {
    width: 95%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .wrap {
    margin: 2rem 0;
    max-width: 50%;
    justify-self: center;
  }
  .nav-buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1rem;
    width: 80%;
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .category-button {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  #products {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 1rem;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .card {
    justify-self: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 1rem;
  }
  .card:first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  .image-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15rem;
  }
  .product-img {
    height: 15rem;
  }
  .content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  .wrap {
    max-width: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .wrap {
    max-width: 65%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .wrap {
    max-width: 65%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .wrap {
    max-width: 70%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .wrap {
    max-width: 75%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .wrap {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .image-container {
    height: 12rem;
  }
  .product-img {
    height: 12rem;
  }
}


/*Giovanni Perillo idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79096321/how-to-remove-styling-if-the-heght-of-the-screen-less-than-the-element-height*/

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  .wrap {
    position: static;
    top: 15%;
    transform: none;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    width: 85%;
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>SayHiShi - Restaurant Menu</title>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body id="body">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h1 class="logo-phrase">SayHiSus<span class="logo-phrase-red">Hi</span></h1>
    <hr class="hr-h1">
    <nav class="nav-buttons">
      <button class="category-button">Salmon</button>
      <button class="category-button">Tuna</button>
      <button class="category-button">Unagi</button>
      <button class="category-button">Shrimp</button>
      <button class="category-button">Veggie</button>
    </nav>
    <div id="products"></div>
  </div>
</body>



codepen

I can’t reproduce the problem.  Screen is shorter than the wrap element, nothing is cut off.  Maybe it only occurs on certain screen widths?

Use a media query

Is your problem with this<h1 class="logo-phrase"> tag?

Using the CSS3 @Media, you can achieve any responsive condition; for this case, I suggest using the aspect-ratio
//width >= height
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) { 
     .wrap{
         //your CSS here
     }
}

//Or width <= height
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) { 
     .wrap{
         //your CSS here
     }
}

This way you can create conditions for the CSS to be responsive to the situation.
For more options, I recommend reading MDN (since I feel like W3Schools are lacking examples)
Edit: I moved the comments // because they can't be inside the @media

The strictly answer I can make to your question is this snippet below:


// Listening to the events in the case the display frame changes...
// With a custom listener:
window.addEventListener('resize', customListener);
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', customListener);
// Without a custom listener:
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', updateAllContainerMeasurements);
window.addEventListener('deviceorientationabsolute', updateAllContainerMeasurements);

// Just an example of a custom listener.
function customListener ()
{
  // Updating multiple classes.
  updateAllContainerMeasurements({classList: 'myContainer;myOtherContainer'});
  updateAllContainerMeasurements({classList: ['myContainer', 'myOtherContainer']});
  
  // Updating different reduced class than default configuration.
  updateAllContainerMeasurements({reducedClass: 'minimizeContainer'});
};

// The default listener.
function updateAllContainerMeasurements ( theConfiguration )
{
  theConfiguration =
  {
    classList: ['myContainer'],
    reducedClass: 'myReducedContainer',
    
    // Replace the defaults with what's given in the parameter.
    ... Object(theConfiguration)
  };
  
  if ( ! Array.isArray(theConfiguration.classList) )
  {
    theConfiguration.classList =
    (
      String(theConfiguration.classList)
        .replaceAll(';', ' ')
        .replaceAll(',', ' ')
        .split(' ')
    );
  }
  
  for ( const elementClass of theConfiguration.classList )
  {
    // Select your element.
    const allElements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + elementClass.trim());
    
    for ( const theElement of allElements )
    {
      // Saves the original element measurements in itself.
      if ( ! theElement.classList.contains(theConfiguration.reducedClass) )
      {
        theElement.originalMeasurement = theElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      }
      
      // Always verify against the original element measurements.
      if ( window.innerHeight < theElement.originalMeasurement.height )
      {
        if ( ! theElement.classList.contains(theConfiguration.reducedClass) )
        {
          theElement.classList.add(theConfiguration.reducedClass);
        }
      }
      
      else if ( theElement.classList.contains(theConfiguration.reducedClass) )
      {
        theElement.classList.remove(theConfiguration.reducedClass);
      }
    }
  }
}
.myContainer
{
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid darkblue;
}

.minimizeContainer
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid darkred;
}
<div class="myContainer"></div>



Try running the snippet, open Full Page then try resizing the display frame through the Dev Tools.
NOTE: The listener is only observing the height.
EDIT: I did some changes to the snippet:

Adjusted the default listener to observe multiple classes.

1.1. theConfiguration.classList accepts an array with element classes to observe or a string like 'class1,class2;class3 class4'.

Added an example of how to listen with a custom listener.

